# Is it possible to repeat a match in a grep regexp?

Tags: linux, grep, pcre

I am using this:

```
grep '\s[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+\s' file.txt -Po
```

Which will match

```
 ABC DE
 AB AB
 DEF GHIFOO
```

etc

What I want to do is something like

```
grep '\s([A-Z]+)\s%1\s' file.txt -Po
```

to only match

```
 AB AB
 BC BC
 DDD DDD
```

etc.

I can't work out if it's even possible, let alone how.  Is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first captured group should be specified as `\1` not as `%1`:

Sample `file.txt`:

```
AA AB
AB AB
BC BC
DDD DDD
NN WN
```

---

Consider the updated regex patten:

```
grep -Po '\b([A-Z]+)\s\1\s*' file.txt
```

The output:

```
AB AB
BC BC
DDD DDD
```

---

**Bonus** approach for *opposite* action:

```
grep -Po '\b([A-Z]+)\s(?!\1)[A-Z]+\s*' file.txt
```

The output:

```
AA AB
NN WN
```

Comment: @Codemonkey, you got the bonus approach